# Overriding virtual method from base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, pure-virtual

I am writing a small program in Visual C++ 2010. I'm having some trouble **implementing pure virtual functions** inherited from some abstract class, when the classes in question are divided into `*.h` and `*.cpp` files.

This is the Sir.h file where I declare my classes and methods, Sir is a base class:

```
class Sir{
protected : Uint _count; 
            TVint _elemente; 

public : Sir();
         virtual ~Sir(){}
         Uint operator[] (int index);
         Sir& operator() (int index);
         friend ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const Sir &sir);
        
protected : virtual void CalculateValues(int index)=0;
}
class Fibonacci:public Sir{
enum { MAX_FIB = 47 };

using Sir::CalculateValues;
void CalculateValues(int index);
}
```

This is Sir.cpp :

```
 #include "Sir.h"
        
    Sir::Sir(){_count=0;}
        
    Uint Sir::operator[](int index)
                 {
                        if(index<0)
                            ParameterOutOfBounds();
                        else{_count=index+1;}
                        return _elemente[_count];
                 }
    Sir& Sir::operator()(int index){operator[] (index);}
        
    void Fibonacci::CalculateValues(int index){
            
            if(index<Fibonacci::MAX_FIB)
            {Fibonacci::_elemente.push_back(1);
             Fibonacci::_elemente.push_back(1);
             while(_elemente.size()<_count)
            Fibonacci::_elemente.push_back(_elemente[_elemente.size()-1]+_elemente[_elemente.size()-2]);
                }
            else ParameterOutOfBounds();
        
      }
ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const Sir &sir)
       {
          cout<<"Index  Value"<<endl;
          cout<<"--------------------"<<endl;
          for(int i=0;i<_count;i++)
          cout<<i<<"    "<<_elemente[_count]<<endl;
        }
```

This is the testSir.cpp file :

```
#include "Sir.h";
#include<iostream>;
#include"Calc\Exceptions.h";
using namespace std;

int main(){

     Sir * fib=new Fibonacci;
     fib->CalculateValues(1); //Error : function is inaccessible
     system("PAUSE");
     return 0;
}
```

I get the error : Error:function "Sir::CalculateValues" is inaccessible. How can i fix this ?

## EDIT :

The protected was my bad . Now i have another problem at `Sir * fib=new Fibonacci;`
I'm getting "Error: object of abstract class type "Fibonacci" is not allowed".

Comment: Regarding your edit, I don't get that error from your code. However, you clearly haven't posted the code you're compiling, since it's full of syntax errors. It sounds like either you haven't correctly overridden `CalculateValues` (which you have in the posted code), or the real code contains another pure virtual function which you haven't overridden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is inaccessible since its declared as `protected`.

```
protected : virtual void CalculateValues(int index)=0;
```

Add it under `public :` :

```
public : Sir();
         virtual ~Sir(){}
         Uint operator[] (int index);
         Sir& operator() (int index);
         friend ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const Sir &sir);
         virtual void CalculateValues(int index)=0;
```

And the same for the `Fibonacci` class (only the relevant method)

a `protected` method is accessible only to the class declaring it or any of it derivatives

Comment: thank you but now i have another problem with -Sir * fib=new Fibonacci; - "error: object of abstract class type "Fibonacci" is not allowed

Comment: Why are you using the following line : "using Sir::CalculateValues;" ?. And also in your Fibonacci class you need to explictly declare CalculateValues as public like in the parent class. If no access specifier is used than private is the default while it should be public for this method

Answer (score 0):

`CalculateValues` is declared as **protected**, so it can be accessed only from subclasses.of `Sir` class.

Declare it **public** if you want it to be callable from any other class.